# Converting Total Hours with type (double) to formatted time

Tags: c#, timespan

I am getting total hour from this code :

```
string date = Request.Form[DFrom.UniqueID];
string date1 = Request.Form[DTo.UniqueID]; ;

DateTime start = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", null);
DateTime end = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", null);
totaltime = (start - end).TotalHours;
```

Output will be like this :

> 25.44535

I want to convert the total hours to formatted time like this for example : 
44:12:00

Comment: I suspect what you are looking for is not total hour but `(start - end)` itself. `(start - end)` would give you timespan what I believe you are looking for here.

Comment: @Sachin for example i said

Comment: how does `25.44535` become `44:12:00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have *already* a `TimeSpan`, you can format it like;

```
var ts = (start - end);
Console.WriteLine("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Days, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes); // 01:01:26
```

Remember, these `Days`, `Hours` and `Minutes` properties returns whole hours as an `int`. If you look for their fractional parts also, you can use theirs `TotalXXX` properties as well.

With .NET Framework 4.0, [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) introduced. If you have this version or higher, you can use this custom format as well like;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm}", ts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Propably you don't want to convert this to totalHours. You can simply return a `TimeSpan`  `totaltime = (start - end)`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have in format hh:mm:ss, you can do like this:

```
TimeSpan ts = start- end;
string st = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Days*24+ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```